# Retrieve records from database by passing an array

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

**My controller code**

```
public function all_ratings(){
  $result_ratings = $data['result_ratings'] ; 
  **(I have successfully captured '$result_ratings' data here)**

  $first_names = array_column($result_ratings, 'customer_id');
  $data['result_cus'] =$this->mod_customers->get_unique_customer($first_names);

  //var_dump($data['result_cus']); die(); 
  data['related_view']='system_rating_appointments';
  $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

**My model code**(mod_customers)

```
public function get_unique_customer($first_names){
    $this->load->database();     
    $this->db->where('id', $first_names);    
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
    return $query->result_array();
  }
```

**Result**

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM `tbl_customer` WHERE `id` = `Array`

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/theme/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Hi all,I'm new to codeignitor.I want to retrieve records for each value of the array from the above table.But error occurred.Please help me.

Note : database,table defined on top of the model page

Comment: Tip: Instead of using `$this->load->database(); ` every where you can autoload it in config/autoload.php `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Comment: I have already made this,thanku so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `where_in` method as you are supplying array of `$first_names` for the condition :

```
$this->db->where_in('id', $first_names);
```